# Using colormap to create a PIL Image from the luminosity map of an image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have M vectors containing 4096 data points between 0 and 1 that represent the luminosity map of faces. This is a sample of the actual images.

[image]

Now, my purpose is to put them in a plotly visual, but to do so I need to provide a PIL object representing the image, This is my MVC

```
import PIL.Image as pilim
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

greys = cm.get_cmap('Greys')
num_images = 10
num_faces = faces.shape[0]
sample_images = np.random.choice(num_faces, num_images, replace=False)

for index in sample_images:
     greyscale = np.apply_along_axis(greys, 0, faces[index]).reshape((64, 64, 4))
     im = pilim.fromarray(greyscale, mode='RGBA')
     im.save('test{}.png'.format(index))    greys = cm.get_cmap('Greys')
```

Faces is a ndarray with 698 samples. Something like the following sample

```
[[0.01617647 0.01617647 0.01617647 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.01617647 0.01617647 0.01617647 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.01617647 0.01617647 0.01617647 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

and this is my depressing result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) works with pixel data, so each of RGBA is a value from 0 to 255. A colormap default generates its RGBA values in the range 0-1. To convert them, you could multiply those by 255 and convert to 8 bit unsigned integers (uint8), like so:

```
greyscale = np.uint8(cmap(faces[index].reshape(64,64)) * 255)
```

But, matplotlib's colormaps also support a parameter to directly generate those bytes:

```
greyscale = cmap(faces[index].reshape(64,64), bytes=True)
```

You could reshape your arrays afterwards to (64,64,4), but it is easier and more readable to do the conversion before applying the colormap.

There is a choice of several [sequential colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#sequential) for this type of images. Appending an `_r` to the name gives the reverse colormap (so dark and light reversed).

Here is some code to get you started:

```
import PIL.Image as pilim
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cmap = cm.get_cmap('copper_r') # 'bone_r', 'Greys', 'copper_r', 'Purple', ...
num_images = 1

faces = np.tile(np.linspace(0,1,4096), 698).reshape(698, 4096)

num_faces = faces.shape[0]
sample_images = np.random.choice(num_faces, num_images, replace=False)
print(sample_images)
for index in sample_images:
     greyscale = cmap(faces[index].reshape(64,64), bytes=True)
     im = pilim.fromarray(greyscale, mode='RGBA')
     im.save(f'test{index}.png')
```

PS: There is also an [`imsave`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) function in matplotlib, which would further simplify the code:

```py
for index in sample_images:
     plt.imsave(f'test{index}.png', faces[index].reshape(64,64), cmap=cmap)
```

If the image would show up upside down, adding `origin='lower'` to `imsave` would reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually pretty simple. There are two steps missing on my code:

1. re-scale to 0-255 values
2. Cast to uint8 in order to PIL to understand the array

   greyscale = np.apply_along_axis(greys, 0, faces[index]).reshape((64, 64, 4))*255
   greyscale = greyscale.astype(np.uint8)
   im = pilim.fromarray(greyscale)

https://python-decompiler.com/article/2012-06/how-to-convert-numpy-array-to-pil-image-applying-matplotlib-colormap

Comment: Or just `greyscale = greys(faces[index].reshape(64,64), bytes=True)`