# Attempting to create an image from a luminosity map

Tags: image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, colormap

I've loaded a dataset containing images where each is given as a 64x64 luminosity map. These are stored as a vector having shape (4096, 698). So far I've loaded the images from a matlab file and reshaped the images, but the function I've written to process the images is returning only 64x64 images of dots. I've also tried the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251872/using-colormap-to-create-a-pil-image-from-the-luminosity-map-of-an-image), but it returned only images of solid black.

Here is an example of what my function is returning:
[image: White and gray dots on black background]

Here is an example of what I need to achieve:
[image: Small head from an angle]

My code so far appears below. I'm including the line where I reshape my data set in case that's contributing to the issue. I think the issue is with the application of the colormap, but I'm probably wrong on that. Can anybody help me rethink this approach?

```
# Reshape - these will be luminosity maps
image_data = q3_data['images'].reshape(-1, 64, 64)

def luminosityToImage(luminosity_maps, output_dir='data/isomap_data', colormap='gray'):
    '''
    Converts a luminosity map to a PIL image via colormap.
    APPLY THIS AFTER RESHAPING IMAGE ROWS.
    '''
    # Create directory to store images if doesn't already exist
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    # Define the colormap
    cmap = cm.get_cmap(colormap)
    # Number of images
    num_images = luminosity_maps.shape[0]
    # Iterate over the luminosity maps
    for index in range(num_images):
        # Normalize the luminosity map
        normalized_map = luminosity_maps[index] / np.max(luminosity_maps[index])
        
        # Apply the colormap
        colored_map = cmap(normalized_map)
        
        # Convert to uint8
        colored_map_uint8 = (colored_map * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        
        # Convert to PIL image
        im = Image.fromarray(colored_map_uint8, mode='RGBA')
        
        # Save the image
        im.save(os.path.join(output_dir, f'image_{index}.png'))
```